# how to call a event on setting value to datepicker on angular kendo date picker

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui

Im having two date pickers (start date and end date ) in my angular form I want to set min value of my end date as start date. I invoked a method on value change in start date which set min value to end date (setting start date as min date to end date). When I open a form in the edit mode, filled the data , at that time I want to set min value of end date based on start date.Due to this I am getting validation error. (previously assigned [min] is still exist in the this.min variable I want ti reset it ) How to do this?

```
   <kendo-datepicker 
        formControlName="startDate" placeholder="Start Date" [format]="'MM/dd/yyyy'" (valueChange)=selectedStartDate() required>
   </kendo-datepicker>

   <kendo-datepicker 
        formControlName="endDate" placeholder="END Date" [format]="'MM/dd/yyyy'" [min] = "min" required>
   </kendo-datepicker>
```

app.component.ts

```
    min:Date;
    public selectedStartDate(){
        const formModel = this.specialDayFormGroup.value;
         if (formModel.startDate) {
          this.min = new Date(formModel.startDate);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
            <kendo-datepicker
                [min]="min"
                [max]="max"
                [(ngModel)]="value"
                #dateModel="ngModel"
                (valueChange)=selectedStartDate()
            ></kendo-datepicker>

            <kendo-datepicker
                [min]="min2"
                [(ngModel)]="value2"
                #dateModel="ngModel"
            ></kendo-datepicker>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    public min: Date = new Date(2020, 4, 10);
    public max: Date = new Date(2020, 9, 10);
    public value: Date = new Date(2020, 4, 10);    
    
    public min2: Date = new Date(2020, 4, 10);
    public value2: Date = new Date(2020, 4, 10);

    public selectedStartDate(){
      this.min2 = this.value;
    }
}
```